# Change linux multicast interface

Tags: routing, multicast

Why my multicast traffic always goes through wlan0 interface?

I try

```
ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev lo
ip link set dev lo multicast on
ip route flush cache
```

But VLC casting to 224.0.0.1:1111 always goes through wlan0 interface.

**ip route:**

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.102  metric 600 
224.0.0.0/4 dev lo  scope link
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem you are running into is VLC is defaulting to the interface of your default route, but you need the device of the default route to be a different network card.

You can't have two default routes but you can do a little hackary to get around this.

1) Set the default route to be the network card you want to receive multicast packets on. For example eth4

```
ip route del default
ip route add default dev eth4
```

Your computer will no longer be able to route traffic to your gateway so your internet will break.

2) To fix it route all traffic to your gateway.

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via (ip of gateway) dev wan1
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via (ip of gateway) dev wan1
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev lo table local
```

verify with

```
ip route get 224.0.0.1
```